# Compare dates using relational operators in google big query

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to select the records whose DateTime in table tb2 is greater than or equal to MinDateTime of tb1and whose DateTime of tb2 is less MaxDateTime of table tb1.

I am getting the error “Error: ON clause must be AND of = comparisons of one field name from each table, with all field names prefixed with table name.”

Not sure whether i am not allowed to compare dates like this in the query.

```
SELECT
 *
FROM (
    SELECT
        c.Id2 AS Id,
        d.DateTime AS DateTime,
        c.Latitude AS Latitude,
        c.Longitude AS Longitude
    FROM (
            SELECT
                Id1,MAX(DateTime) AS MaxDatetime,
                MIN(DateTime) AS MinDateTime
            FROM [tb1]
            GROUP BY VehicleId) AS d
    INNER JOIN (
         SELECT
                Latitude, Longitude, Id2, DateTime
                FROM [tb2]) AS c
ON
    d.Id1 = c.Id2
    AND c.DateTime >= d.MinDateTime
    AND c.DateTime < d.MaxDateTime)
```

Comment: run it in BigQuery Standard SQL - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/enabling-standard-sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on Mikhail's note:

BigQuery legacy SQL requires that join conditions are simple equalities. Using [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/enabling-standard-sql) (uncheck "Use Legacy SQL" under "Show Options") you should be able to execute the query with just a small adjustment of escaping the table names with backticks `` ` `` instead, something like:

```
SELECT
 *
FROM (
    SELECT
        c.Id2 AS Id,
        d.DateTime AS DateTime,
        c.Latitude AS Latitude,
        c.Longitude AS Longitude
    FROM (
            SELECT
                Id1,MAX(DateTime) AS MaxDatetime,
                MIN(DateTime) AS MinDateTime
            FROM `tb1`
            GROUP BY VehicleId) AS d
    INNER JOIN (
         SELECT
                Latitude, Longitude, Id2, DateTime
                FROM `tb2`) AS c
ON
    d.Id1 = c.Id2
    AND c.DateTime >= d.MinDateTime
    AND c.DateTime < d.MaxDateTime);
```

If you do want to execute the query using legacy SQL, you will need to express the non-equality conditions for the join as a separate filter, e.g.:

```
SELECT
 *
FROM (
    SELECT
        c.Id2 AS Id,
        d.DateTime AS DateTime,
        c.Latitude AS Latitude,
        c.Longitude AS Longitude
    FROM (
            SELECT
                Id1,MAX(DateTime) AS MaxDatetime,
                MIN(DateTime) AS MinDateTime
            FROM [tb1]
            GROUP BY VehicleId) AS d
    INNER JOIN (
         SELECT
                Latitude, Longitude, Id2, DateTime
                FROM [tb2]) AS c
ON
    d.Id1 = c.Id2
WHERE
    c.DateTime >= d.MinDateTime
    AND c.DateTime < d.MaxDateTime)
```